# Command to automate the differentiation SailfishOS+Alien Dalvik from an android device

Tags: linux, command-line, android

EDIT0 : I have 3 smartphones :

One Jolla1 smartphone with SailfishOS v3 + Alien Dalvik and 2 android smartphones.

I want to be able to differentiate them in shell language :

On my Jolla1 Linux :

```bash
$ uname -s
Linux
$ getprop ro.build.version.release
4.1.2
$ uname -a 
Linux myJolla1 3.4.108.20190506.1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 9 18:24:45 UTC 2019 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

On my first android smartphone via `adb shell` :

```bash
shell@hlteatt:/ $ getprop ro.build.version.release
5.0
shell@hlteatt:/ $ uname -s
/system/bin/sh: uname: not found
127|shell@hlteatt:/ $ uname -a
/system/bin/sh: uname: not found
```

On my second android smartphone via `adb shell` :

```bash
BV9500Pro:/ $ uname -s
Linux
BV9500Pro:/ $ getprop ro.build.version.release
8.1.0
BV9500Pro:/ $ uname -a                                                                                                                             
Linux localhost 4.4.95 #9 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 20 18:03:34 CST 2019 aarch64
```

I tried this but both devices have the `getprop` tool so this does not work :

```bash
getprop 2>/dev/null | grep -q ro.build.version.release && export osFamily=Android || export osFamily=$(uname -s)
```

BTW : [SailfishOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailfish_OS#Software_architecture) is a true Linux based on the Linux kernel + the [Mer project software distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mer_%28software_distribution%29#Software_architecture) (the last being forked from the discontinued [MeeGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MeeGo) Linux distribution)

Answer (score 1):

You can get three distinct responses back from `uname -m` and make use of that.

We expect a failure response from the device without `uname`, but we suppress the error and take the empty response as our indicator.

```
case "$(uname -m 2>/dev/null)" in
  (armv7l)  DEVICE=Jolla ;;
  (aarch64) DEVICE=Android1 ;;
  ("")      DEVICE=Android2 ;;
  (*)       DEVICE=UNKNOWN ;;
esac
```

Whilst we could refer to the software version numbers, these may well change when/if the OS is updated. Using the hardware info is more reliable under your current circumstances, but will elicit false positives if you get further devices which share the same hardware architecture.

Comment: No it's not because the second Android device also has the `uname` command installed, your solution will return `Linux` for both the SailfishOS device and the second Android device

Comment: I see, my comment was a little confusing. In this comment, I meant, "the first Android device has the `uname tool`"

Comment: As the question states : I have 3 smartphones : one on SailfishOS (has `uname` tool), another on Android (has `uname`) and the 3rd one on Android (does not have the `uname` tool)

Comment: But I agree, it'a little confusing so I'm going to update the question rightaway

Comment: OK I better understand now, I hadn’t appreciated you were looking at 3 phones before. Don’t feel like I have the full picture here. What does `uname -a` display on each phone? What does `getprop ro.build.version.release` display on each phone? What’s the significance of the `rpm` list you posted?

Comment: I've removed the `rpm` list because it was off topic for this question.
Please reload the page to see the updates I've done.

Comment: Your best option is probably to pull the machine info from `uname`. Will update my answer.

Comment: Oops, somehow missed the `-m` flag off, fixed.

Comment: `uname -m`, which stands for `uname --machine` does not really help identifying the underlying OS. It may work for my specific case but if I try this on other android devices, I'm not sure it's going to return the same result. So I'm going to upvote your answer, but I still be waiting for another suggestion than `uname`

Comment: I think any solution is going to have limitations, and will probably require further work down the road to handle edge cases and things you don’t know yet. Just depends on how much time you want to spend on a solution versus how much time it saves you.

Comment: I agree with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to install bash (the Termux app for example) on all the android devices and have the script test the `OSTYPE` bash variable :

One the android 8.1 device, the `OSTYPE` bash variable equals `linux-android` (see the screenshot below)

Therefore the command to differentiate will be :

```
echo $OSTYPE | grep -q android && export osFamily=Android || export osFamily=$(uname -s)
```

[image]